# ALM11 OTA API Error for Unattached test sets: No post allowed for object that has virtual father

Tags: hp-quality-center, hp-alm

In HP-ALM 11, moving test sets from the 'Unattached' folder to any other folder in the test lab, using the OTA API throws the below exception:

'No post allowed for object that has virtual father'

The exception is thrown at the 'post' below:

> TS.TestSetFolder = DestFolder; TS.Post();

The same works in QC10. Need your help please.

**Additional info:**

Setting the destination test set folder for test sets is the way to move the test sets from one folder to another in the test lab, which works for test sets in any other folder except for the Unattached folder using ALM11 OTA API. The problem is not seen in QC10 (using QC10 OTA API).

Comment: I have no problem changing the TestSetFolder of a test set located in the Unattached folder to move it in ALM11 using the OTA API. Works as expected, and as described in the API Reference, and as described by you. Maybe a configuration issue? A possible workaround might be to copy the test set with the `CopyToClipBoard` method, paste it with `PasteFromClipBoard` and then delete it from the Unattached folder.

Comment: Hi Roland, I'm using http://qc1d.atlanta.hp.com/qcbin/ for ALM11.

Comment: Roland, did you use qc1d or qc2d or ... for ALM11?